# Connected graph where edge costs depend on a parameter $t$. Find the $t^*$ which gives the minimum cost minimum spanning tree.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

**The set-up:**  Let $G=(\,V,\,E\,)$ be a connected graph. Associated with every edge $e\in E$ is a cost/weight *function* $f_e(t) = a_e t^2 + b_e t + c_e $, where $a_e>0$. For a fixed $t$ we can define and find a Minimum Spanning Tree on $G$ in the usual way. Let $c_G(t)$ be the cost that MST, and then letting $t$ range over $\mathbb{R} $ we see $c_G(t)$ gives the cost of a MST on $G$ as a function of the parameter $t$.

**The problem:**  Design an (greedy) algorithm to find $t^* = \underset{t\in \mathbb{R}}{\operatorname{argmin}}  c_G(t)$.

**Note:** This question (a more wordy set-up) is in the "Greedy Algorithms" chapter of the K&T Algorithm Design book I've been reviewing, so there should be a greedy algorithm to solve this...

**My initial thoughts/attempt:** For an arbitrary spanning tree $T$ on $G$ we can find the $t$ which minimizes the cost of *that* spanning tree (basic calculus) and thus also find the minimum possible cost of that spanning tree. Then perhaps there'd be a way to build up or iterate through these trees, at each step moving towards/to spanning trees with lower minimum possible cost. Couldn't come up with a greedy and efficient algorithm to do this, however.

Comment: Your initial thought looks like local search. Note, that the objective function is in general neither convex nor concave: Take a graph with nodes 1, 2, 3, and 4 and edges (1,2), (2,3), and (3,4) with costs $t^2+1$, $1$, and $(t-1)^2+1.1$. Then $c_G(t) = \min(t^2+2, (t-1)^2+2.1)$ which has two local minima at 0 and 1. Thus, a local search approach will most likely fail.